# Solving inequality $x^3-4x>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was sort of finding the roots by doing $x^3-4x>0=x(x^2-4)$

$x = 0, x = -2,x = 2$ for $$x(x-2)(x+2)>0$$

Then I stopped and thought; maybe I shouldn't be doing that? I am doubting myself! Can anyone confirm if I am doing the right thing to solve the equality?

Comment: Are you able to draw the graph for $y = x^3 - 4 x?$

Comment: I think so. I have it at $+\infty$ for $ x= 2$ $-\infty$ for $ x= -2$ and cutting through zero

Comment: Please try the graph, with specific $x$ values $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ which give nice integer $y$ values. For example, $3^3 - 4 \cdot 3 = 27 - 12 = 15.$ Your manipulation of the $\infty$ symbol makes little sense.

Comment: At $x=-2$ the value is not $-\infty$ but $0$ as your factorization shows.

Comment: but what about the not integer values? I have tried it to be $$f(x)>0 $$ for the values of $x$: $$ x>2, -2<x<0 $$

Comment: I meant to write tends to infinity @RossMillikan, it won't let me edit for some reason.

Comment: Comments cannot be edited after some time (5 minutes?).  You can delete and resubmit as a workaround, but sometimes it confuses things to take it out of order.

Comment: Yes, I think i will leave it. My latex is not good enough to cope with only two edits and no preview, so I won't attempt it again here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-4x$ is $0$ at $x=-2, 0,$ and $2.$ At $-3$ the value of the polynomial is $< 0$; at $3$ the value is $>0.$ At $-1,$ the value is $>0.$ At $1$ the value is $<0.$

From this we see the polynomial is $> 0$ for
$$-2<x<0 \text{ and } x>2.$$

Comment: ah ok I didn't see this! I think this is right, so I am going to accept.

Comment: Are we just supposed to find this out by trial and error? Isn't there a standard method?

Comment: @David - when a continuous function changes sign it passes through zero (intermediate value theorem) - so to find out where a continuous function is positive it is necessary to identify where (if anywhere) it takes the value zero - in some way or another this is what any analysis will do. A function need not change sign at a zero ($y=x^2$), so some attention is required at each zero. The method is perfectly systematic. [for no zero one can look to express the function in such a way that this becomes obvious eg $y=(x-4)^2+1$]

Answer (score 4):

I like to do tables to determine signs. It follows from Bolzano's Theorem the sign will be kept between the roots. You already factored this and obtained $x=2,x=-2,x=0$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 & (-\infty,-2) & (-2,0)& (0,2)&(2,+\infty)\\ \hline
x-2 & - &- & -&+\\  \hline
x+2 &- &+  &+ &+\\ \hline
x & - & - &+ &+\\ \hline
p(x)& -&+&-&+\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

**Explanation**: The top row is the real line divided into the intervals by the roots we have. The first three rows of $+/-$ account for the sign of the factors in each interval, which we obtain by inspection. Finally, the sign of $p$ is obtained by "multiplying" each of the values obtained, so $-\times-\times-=-$, $-\times+\times +=+$,$\&c$.

Try and do the same for $p(x)={x^3} + 4{x^2} + 3x - 2$.

Comment: Can someone fix the table?

Comment: Yikes! Not sure what's up, there. Might want to post to/ check the meta about such issues.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to draw a number line and mark the places where the polynomial is zero. The sign will be constant in the intervals so created.  Check inside each one to see the sign (+ or -).  Then it's easy to read the solution.

Comment: You are assuming polynomials are continuous (which they are): this would not work for $\tan x = 0$.

Comment: Correct.  This procedure applies to polynomials, and more generally, to continuous functions.   It does generalize for rational functions. Put a white dot at each zero of the denominator. That point is excluded from the domain.  Along with the (filled) dots at the zeroes, the function's sign is constant between dots.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach.  You are almost there.  A product is positive if it has an even number of negative terms.  So it is positive if there are no negative terms, which is if $x \gt 2$, or if there are two negative terms ...

Comment: I wrote where I got with this in a comment above. I think I get it now, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Magpie:  You are correct in the comment.  You can see it in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3-4x  The three roots, $-2, 0, 2$ are where the function crosses zero and divide the positive regions from the negative ones.